# getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds; returns 0 after onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get the `LatLngBounds` from the Visible Region on the device's screen after my Google map has been initialized. However I only receive a 0 values. My guess is that the map has not actually been loaded, even after `OnMapReady` has been called. I've looked all over for a better way of checking for map initialization and found nothing. How do I ensure I receive the correct data?

**INITIALIZE MAP**

```
public void initMap(){
    MapFragment map = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    map.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

**ON MAP READY CALLBACK**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {    

    try {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
            mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
            mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            search();
        }

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        mUtility.getThemedAlert(this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.error_google_maps),
                getResources().getString(R.string.unable_build_google_maps)).show();
    }
}
```

**GET BOUNDS**

```
public void search() {
    LatLngBounds bounds = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    Log.e("TEST", bounds.toString());
}
```

**LOG OUTPUT**

```
E/TEST﹕ LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (0.0,0.0), northeast=lat/lng: (0.0,0.0)}
```

Comment: mm that's not a good thing... where is the map zoomed when you start (the lat/lng bounds are retrieved)? Did you try to make some test about delaying the call (with handlers.postDelayed or similar) just to test if it is a problem of timing?
What if you try to move the camera by code and then call the "search()" function?
My idea is that bounds are set by the APIs only when there is a camera change, and this would be a bug to fill!

Comment: How about the [OnMapLoaded](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.html#onMapLoaded())? this should be called after all the tiles are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

OnMapLoaded function helps. Thank you.

Here is my code,

```
map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLoaded() {

                    invokeApi();
                }
});
```